# SQL Server Comparing (dev) table column contents against (prod) table column contents

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, comparison

I need to compare the contents of the same table in different environments dev & prod. One of the development table columns needs to match the production table.

The query is executed from the production environment.

The queries that I have so far, one uses OPENQUERY to retrieve the data from the development db server, and the other one is the query that gets the data from production, These are not joined, these are two separate queries right now.

Ideally I would like to run this as a stored procedure, and see 3 columns: dev_value, prod_value, and a third column that shows which lines are either different, or extra lines that are found in development, but not in production.

Most likely I will eventually have to clean up those all values that were probably added sometime during development but never completed.

My queries:

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM Prod.dbo.DOMAIN
WHERE DOMAIN_VALUE = 'AdminHold'

SELECT VALUE
FROM OPENQUERY(
    [Dev],
    'SELECT * FROM [Dev].[dbo].[DOMAIN] WHERE DOMAIN_VALUE = ''AdminHold'''
)
```

Any help or suggestions/ examples on how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about using the Visual Studio SQL Server data comparison?

I am not sure how suitable this would be; it depends what you want to do with the results I suppose.

In Visual Studio Professional 2017, it can be found in the Tools menu, then SQL Server, then New Data Comparsion. After the comparison is complete, you can update the target database, generate scripts etc.

Comment: Crogacht - Your suggestion sound good and practical. Unfortunately I am not able to use VS for this task. Thank you though.